# How to form search query in Elastic search Query DSL in python for geo points?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
{
  "geo_bounding_box": {
    "location": {
      "top_right": {
        "lat": 4.482137,
        "lon": 51.0355306
      },
      "bottom_left": {
        "lat": 4.482137,
        "lon": 51.0146768
      }
    }
  }
} .
```

Convert the above search filter to Elastic search query DSL.(Python)

Comment: I am able to apply direct filters. But not able to find a way for geo_points ?

Comment: .filter("geo_bounding_box", location = { "top_right" : {"lat": 4.482137, "lon": 51.0355306   },
                      "bottom_left" : { "lat": 4.482137,  "lon": 51.0146768 }}).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/filter.py), you will find `geo_bounding_box filter`, your script should look something like this

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search(using=client, index="my_index") \
    .filter("geo_bounding_box", location={
            "top_right": {
              "lat": 4.482137,
              "lon": 51.0355306
            },
            "bottom_left": {
              "lat": 4.482137,
              "lon": 51.0146768
            }
          })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, was looking for this. Is there a way to write this as a class by inheriting from `from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Query`?

Answer (score 0):

.filter("geo_bounding_box", location = { "top_right" : {"lat": 4.482137, "lon": 51.0355306 }, "bottom_left" : { "lat": 4.482137, "lon": 51.0146768 }}).

This will work !